Mystery border/highlight in JavaScript
I'm a beginner and could use some help. I used this W3Schools script to copy a discount code on my Shopify site.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_copy_clipboard2
(this is the same code from W3Schools:)


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click on the button to copy the text from the text field. Try to paste the text (e.g. ctrl+v) afterwards in a different window, to see the effect.</p>

<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">

<div class="tooltip">
<button onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
  <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
  Copy text
  </button>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>



I have it set up pretty well, but ran into an issue. When you click copy, the input field border gets bold or wider and the text turns white and highlighted in blue. For some reason, on my site, it adds a second gray border surrounding the input field/border, and the text stays black with a gray highlight.
No matter what I try with CSS in styles or in the script at the bottom. I can't make any changes to this after-click border and highlight without messing up something else.
I don't see anything in the code controlling this.
Any ideas?
Again, no matter what I try with CSS in styles or in the script at the bottom. I can't make any changes to this after-click border and highlight without messing up something else.


Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to ask a good question. Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add all the relevant code to include a [mre].

There is code controlling this. Its copyText.select();. to unselect it just use: window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); look at my answer for more info and the full code

Stops the text highlight, not the border.

to unselect the input box, just use myInput.blur(); basically stops the border highlight.

Sorry. I applied it wrong. myInput.blur(); eliminates border and highlight.

Would it be difficult to use a copy icon instead of the Copy text button?

@Truder Harassing people on SO to get your answer marked correct is insane. This isn't Reddit, not everyone is refreshing repeatedly looking for validation/a fight.

A solution to this problem is to deselect it with the JavaScript code. You can use window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); to unselect the input box. Just use your-input-id.blur();.
Full example


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click on the button to copy the text from the text field. Try to paste the text (e.g. ctrl+v) afterwards in a different window, to see the effect.</p>

<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">

<div class="tooltip">
<button onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
  <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
  Copy text
  </button>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  const myInput = document.querySelector('input'); // Replace with your input selector
myInput.blur(); // Unselect the input field

  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>



